# Unable to make the trademark symbol bold using sup tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am actually trying to make the trademark symbol bold and tried the below options. However, it is not working not sure what else i can try to make the trademark symbol bold? Any suggestions please.

```
Option 1  : <p>This text contains <strong><sup>&#174;</sup></strong> text.</p>
Option 2  : <p>This text contains <b><sup>&#174;</sup></b> text.</p>
```

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want a ™ symbol or a raised ® symbol?

Comment: I just played around with this a bit, and even at a large font size (36px), not superscripted, and in a couple of different fonts, the ® symbol just doesn't seem to have much capability for becoming very bold.

Comment: I actually looking to get this ® symbol bold. Seems like there is no options i believe to do this via html and css. Either I should use and image or try fontAwesome.

Comment: As I explain in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58193495/12060289), your code *is* making it bold, but it's hard to see.

Answer (score 3):

Your code *is* making it bold, but the ® is so small (especially in a superscript) that it is extremely difficult to see the difference. The snippet below shows your code (first line) which indeed makes the symbol bold, and the same code without the `<strong>` tags (second line) to show the visual difference. Both have been enlarged.

Note that some fonts already show the ® symbol as a superscript. (e.g. Consolas and Calibri) Helvetica (the main font on StackOverflow) and Times New Roman (the default font in most browsers, which also applies to Stack code snippets) do not show the ® symbol as raised. The point is this: make sure the font you use doesn't already make it a superscript.

If you wish to make the symbol more bold than the bold style of your font, you would need to use a different font just for the symbol or use an image.

```html
<p style="font-size:200%">This text contains <strong><sup>&reg;</sup></strong> text.</p>
<p style="font-size:200%">This text contains <sup>&reg;</sup> text.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it should work. But in my case it was hardly noticeable (but definitely a small change).

You could try using css to make it bold, if the style is overridden.

```
-- HTML
<p>This text contains <span class="bold-text"><sup>&#174;</sup></span> text.</p>

-- CSS
.bold-text {
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

Or you could use an image instead.
`<p>This text contains <img src="restricted.png" alt="restricted image"> text.</p>`

Just some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you could use [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=trademark), which provides free and lightweight icons. See the [documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use) on how to use it.